# browser showing connection was reset while accessing posts from local host

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, single

I was coding a custom theme. Posts showing connection reset problem message where as pages are loading fine. I found adding js to my single.php causing this error.here is my code to add js file.

```
function adding_sidebar_js(){
   if( is_single() {
       wp_enqueue_scripts( 'singlejs', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/sidebar.js' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adding_sidebar_js' );
```

Can you explain why I am getting this error?

Comment: Which file contains that code?

Comment: functions.php, problem solved it was `wp_enqueue_scripts` causing problem. it was actually `wp_enqueue_script`

Comment: Please, post it as an answer so other users can find it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was syntex error in my functions.php which causing the error.
In the if statement it was not `wp_enqueue_scripts`. It was `wp_enqueue_script`